# How to add blank rows or custom header in excel export file in datatables?

Tags: jquery, datatable

How to add some blank rows in datatables exported excel file?

I am trying to add headers into an excel file and I tried many approaches but none of them are working for me.

If no one knows how to do that a hint how to add blank rows in excel would also be useful for me.

My simple code at the moment is below and I wanted to know what I can add to it  to make it work for excel export as I've already found a solution for pdf and csv but not for excel file:

```
$('#invoice_data').dataTable( {
    ordering: true,"autoWidth": false,
    paging: true,
    searching: true,
    dom: 'Bftripl',
    buttons: [
        'excelHtml5',
        'csvHtml5',
        'pdfHtml5'
    ]
});
```

Following is another try, where I am trying to add blank row but it's not working:

```
var buttonCommon = {
    exportOptions: {
        format: {
            header: function ( data, row, column, node ) {
                // Strip $ from salary column to make it numeric
                return column === 1 ?
                    "llll "+row+" nd "+node :
                    data+"KKK "+row+" nd "+node;
            }
        }
    }
};
 $('#invoice_data').DataTable({
    ordering: true,"autoWidth": false,
    paging: true,
    searching: true,
    dom: 'Bftripl',
    buttons: [
        $.extend( true, {}, buttonCommon, {
            extend: 'copyHtml5'
        } ),
        $.extend( true, {}, buttonCommon, {
            extend: 'excelHtml5'
        } ),
        $.extend( true, {}, buttonCommon, {
            extend: 'pdfHtml5'
        } )
    ]
} );
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So finally I have found a solution to this so my code is capable to place header in Excel, PDF, CSV file in datatable. As I have found it's really hard to find an answer for this, so I am placing my code here. So that anyone can use it.

Before placing below code, download and store the file for version 1.2.2. you can find link here: [version 1.2.2 link](https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/) and download following file [//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/buttons.html5.js](http:////cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/buttons.html5.js)

So place following code line before my DataTable code (I have placed above downloaded file to js folder and then rename to "buttons_export_config_header.js"):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/buttons_export_config_header.js">
```

I have altered line number 1129 to 1131 where I have placed following code in above file:

```
if ( config.header) {
         var tablecaption = [config.message];
  addRow( tablecaption, rowPos );
         //addRow( "testing", "0" );
          addRow( "", rowPos );
        addRow( data.header, rowPos );
        //$('row c', rels).attr( 's', '2' ); // bold
    }
```

I am really thankful to following link: 
[datatables post](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/39257/excel-output-possible-to-add-message-header-using-customize-option)

```
$('#invoice_data').DataTable({
    ordering: true,"autoWidth": false,
    paging: true,
    searching: true,
    dom: 'Bftripl',
    buttons: [
    {
            extend: 'excelHtml5',

            title: 'Any title for file',
            message: "Any message for header inside the file. I am not able to put message in next row in excel file but you can use \n"


        },
        {
            extend: 'csvHtml5',
            title: 'Any title for the file',
             customize: function (csv) {
                 return "Any heading for the csv file can be separated with , and for new line use \n"+csv;
              }
        },
        {
            extend: 'pdfHtml5',
            title: 'Any title for file',
            customize: function ( doc ) {
                            doc.content.splice( 0, 0, {
                                text: "custom header\n my header"
                            } );
            }
        }

        //'excelHtml5',
        //'csvHtml5',
        //'pdfHtml5'
    ] 

});
```

I am glad that I have found solution by myself.:)

Comment: Correct line ->
message: 'Any message for header inside the file. I am not able to put message in next row in excel file but you can use \n'.

Answer (score 1):

i Found solution

---

```
buttons: [
            {extend: 'excelHtml5',
            title: 'Report',
            text:'<i class="fa fa-table fainfo" aria-hidden="true" ></i>',
            titleAttr: 'Export Excel',
            "oSelectorOpts": {filter: 'applied', order: 'current'},
            exportOptions: {
                    modifier: {
                    page: 'all'
                    },
                        format: {
                            header: function ( data, columnIdx ) {
                                if(columnIdx==1){
                                return 'column_1_header';
                                }
                                else{
                                return data;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                }
            ]
```

---

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for multiple row headers in excel:

```
if ( config.header) {
        var tablecaption = [config.message];
        if ($.isArray(tablecaption[0])) {
            $.each(tablecaption[0], function(i, caption) {
                addRow( [caption], rowPos );                                        
                rowPos++;
            });
        } else {
            addRow( tablecaption, rowPos );
            addRow( "", rowPos );               
        }
        addRow( data.header, rowPos );  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to replace header and add merged cells instead

```
extend: 'excelHtml5',
text: 'export to Excel',
customize: function (xlsx) {

    //copy _createNode function from source
    function _createNode(doc, nodeName, opts) { 
        var tempNode = doc.createElement(nodeName);

        if (opts) {
            if (opts.attr) {
                $(tempNode).attr(opts.attr);
            }

            if (opts.children) {
                $.each(opts.children, function (key, value) {
                    tempNode.appendChild(value);
                });
            }

            if (opts.text !== null && opts.text !== undefined) {
                tempNode.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(opts.text));
            }
        }

        return tempNode;
    }

    var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];
    var mergeCells = $('mergeCells', sheet);
    mergeCells[0].children[0].remove(); // remove merge cell 1st row

    var rows = $('row', sheet);
    rows[0].children[0].remove(); // clear header cell

    // create new cell
    rows[0].appendChild(_createNode(sheet, 'c', {
        attr: {
            t: 'inlineStr',
            r: 'B1', //address of new cell
            s: 51 // center style - https://www.datatables.net/reference/button/excelHtml5
        },
        children: {
            row: _createNode(sheet, 'is', {
                children: {
                    row: _createNode(sheet, 't', {
                        text: 'new header text'
                    })
                }
            })
        }
    }));


    // set new cell merged
    mergeCells[0].appendChild(_createNode(sheet, 'mergeCell', {
        attr: {
            ref: 'B1:E1' // merge address
        }
    }));

    mergeCells.attr('count', mergeCells.attr('count') + 1);

    // add another merged cell
}
```