# How to add rows when exporting data into excel in Datatable?

Tags: javascript, excel, datatables

I try to export my datatable into Excel.
Every time when exporting the table I want to add **3 default rows** at the very top.

I saw a datatable message option but that might not help me because I want 3 rows.

#### Actual

Now I have this data (without any extra rows):
[image: without any extra rows]

#### Expected

But I want to export data with these extra rows :
[image: with extra rows]

I have this code right now. and i have tried adding header with message but that didn't work for me because i need 3 header rows.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        lengthChange: false,
        buttons: [{ extend: 'pdf', className: 'btn-success' },
                  { extend: 'print', className: 'btn-success' },
                  { extend: 'excel', className: 'btn-success' } ]
        }
                } 
    );
    
    table.buttons().container()
        .appendTo( '#example_wrapper .col-md-6:eq(0)' );
} );
```

Comment: Just to confirm: You are developing with [JQuery Datatables](https://www.datatables.net/) ? BTW: I edited your post to inline the images and improve the formatting.

Comment: yeah thanks. yes i'm using the Jquery Datatables.

Comment: Then, what did you try on JS-side? Please post your code as [example]. So we can figure out where to add these __3 header-rows__.

Comment: yes can you please check it out now!

Comment: May a similar question inspire you: [how-to-add-blank-rows-or-custom-header-in-excel-export-file-in-datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46106160/how-to-add-blank-rows-or-custom-header-in-excel-export-file-in-datatables)

Answer (score 0):

Assumed you use the [button for Excel export](https://datatables.net/reference/button/excel).

You thought about the [excelHtml5, Option](https://datatables.net/reference/button/excelHtml5#Options) named `messageTop` ?

I would rather add the **3 additional header rows** via [`buttons.exportData( [ options ] )`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/buttons.exportData()).

There you have an option key `customizeData`:

> **function customizeData** (since Buttons 1.5.2) - Function that can be used to modify the data used for the export, after all of it has been gathered and pre-processed by the above formatting options. A single argument is passed in and no return parameter is expected (mutate the object passed in to alter the data):
>
> Data for export. This is an object with the following properties:
>
> - `header` - Array of data for the header
> - `footer` - Array of data for the footer
> - `body` - 2D array of data for the body.

For example add the 3 rows to this `header` array:

```js
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();
 
var data = table.buttons.exportData( {
    customizeData: function(dataForExport) {
        dataForExport.header.push("Header line 1");
        dataForExport.header.push("Header line 2");
        dataForExport.header.push("Header line 3");
    }
} );
// Do something with the 'data' variable
```

Comment: The `messageTop` and `title` attributes can be used - but they will place everything into one Excel row, and Excel will not automatically display embedded line breaks when the file is first opened.

Comment: In the second approach, the `header` property here is an array containing the DataTable column headings. Appending data to this array will add a new column heading to the exportable data. It will not insert a new row in the Excel file above the HTML table data.

Comment: can you please help me how can i use this data variable into my code. Thanks

Comment: @andrewjames Oh, I interpreted "data" in description `Array of data for the header` as _rows_. But _columns_ for a _single header row_ make more sense. Anyway this was a theoretical research answer (untested!).